# fread-ing uint16 in C++?

Tags: c++, fread

I'm trying to read use fread to read in values from an external file in C++. The values are stored as uint16's, which does not seem to exist in C++. I did some googling and found people using typedef to make their own uint16, but I'm also wondering if I could just use fread(ptr, uint8, 2, file) to read two uint8's to be stored in ptr.

Does anyone have any insight to the best way of going about this?

Comment: It looks more like a C question, by the way...

Comment: I'm definitely doing this in C++, which is what the company wants me to do it in. (I'm a first year CS major interning at a small company)

Comment: you may be using a C++ compiler, but the question is plain C, and so are all the answers.... With C++ you can also consider overloading `operator >>` for your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want:

```
fread(ptr, sizeof(uint8), 2, file)
```

Seems OK to me, `fread(ptr, 1, 2, file)` is even better. Or `fread(ptr, sizeof(uint16_t), 1, file)`.

I assume that `ptr` is a pointer pointing to the location where you want to store your data, not the variable itself (if so - use `&ptr`).

Reading two bytes at a time though may become a performance issue, consider reading into a memory buffer, and then parsing it.

Comment: just to clarify, the 1 in fread(ptr, 1, 2, file) just means the size of any int, I could use "8" here and it would still be the same...right? and the 2 means read the size of one int twice

Comment: @Androo - `fread` has 4 parameters. 1st - pointer to the location where to read **to**. Last - pointer to the `FILE*` handle describing where to read **from**. The middle two describe the data: the second parameter is the size of the data block, and the third is the number of blocks you want to read. the 1 in `fread(ptr, 1, 2, file)` means each data block is 1 byte long, and 2 means you want two blocks at a time (i.e.: each call reads 2 bytes). If you replace 1 with 8 - each call will read 16 bytes: 2 blocks 8 bytes each. Read more here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/fread

Comment: in that case, wouldnt fread(ptr, 2, 1, file) work, as the data block would be 2 bytes/16bits, and just 1 block (of 2 bytes)?

Comment: @Androo - yes, it would. That's what `fread(ptr, sizeof(uint16_t), 1, file)` is, precisely.

Comment: I'll use that for now then, though I understand that may be "poor" coding. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 4):

Fixed-size integer types like `uint16_t` are defined in the `<stdint.h>` header. Include that and you'll be in business.

Comment: @duskwuff Does that automatically account for Endian-ness?

Comment: @Chris - That assumes that the data in the file has the endianness of the system it's on.

Comment: @duskwuff Yeah, that's what I thought. I just wanted to point it out in case the OP runs into that problem later.

Comment: including stdint.h required me to include inttypes.h, both of which weren't already in my library. I added both, and when I compile I get lots of syntax errors from inttypes.h. Any advice? Edit: btw, I'm doing this in visual studio

Comment: @Androo Which Visual Studio version?

Comment: @Androo - as mentioned by rubenvb below, 2008 doesn't have this (Microsoft have issues with standard compliance...). Upgrade to 2010. If you can't - you'll have to use proprietary (your own) `typedef` as you described in your question, which is fine too (you can use #ifdef to check the compiler version, if it's less than 2010 - just typedef uint16_t, otherwise #include the headers, and you're done ready for the future).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

Should fix it for you

Answer (score -1):

There are a bunch of fixed sizes you can use, uint16_t and __int16 being the two that would help you in this case.

Comment: `__int16` is Microsoft specific. Avoid using this, and prefer the standard `(u)int16_t` instead.

Comment: He never mentioned his platform, for all you know, he could be using Microsoft, hence why I mentioned both.

Comment: no reason to use non-standard types in cases like this. And before you say VS2008 and earlier don't have `stdint.h`, there are easy enough versions to be found online, and VS2010 has the header.

Comment: @rubenvb: of course there are reasons to use the MS specific types.  How else can MS lock in your code to their platform? :)